# Make tbody with table `class="table table-bordered table-hover"` customizeable height and witdh

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make this table with `class="table table-bordered table-hover"` with customizeable height and width? If yes, how can I make this possible?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table">
        <center>
            <label>ORDER</label>
        </center>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ProductName</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th> Price </th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>X</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to customize height and width of the table?